# Show a series is convergent and calculate numerical sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Calculate:

$\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^3-n}$

I have tried to find the sequence partial sums and show that they converge, but I'm having trouble setting it up and I have no idea how to calcuate the numerical value.

Comment: comparison test. for n big enough n^3 - n > n^2

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110348/find-the-sum-of-infinite-series-frac12-cdot-3-cdot-4-frac14-cdot-5-cd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For convergence, note that

$$n^2<n^3-n\implies\frac1{n^3-n}<\frac1{n^2}$$

Which holds true for $n\ge1$.

---

To evaluate, notice that $n^3-n=n(n-1)(n+1)$, and thus we have a nice PFD:

$$\frac1{n^3-n}=\frac12\left[\frac1{n(n-1)}-\frac1{n(n+1)}\right]$$

Which gives a telescoping series, so,

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^3-n}=\frac14$$

Comment: Note that this is wrong by a factor of $1/2$, compare e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1663085/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Oops, nice catch :D