# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^3-n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^3-n})$

(a)1

(b)$\frac{1}{4}$

(c)$\frac{1}{2}$

(d)$\frac{1}{8}$

**My attempt**:$\frac{1}{n^3-n}=\frac{1}{n}[\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}]$, but this attempt didn't get me to anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve $\frac 1{1.2.3}+\frac 1{2.3.4}+\frac 1{3.4.5}+...$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663080/how-to-solve-frac-11-2-3-frac-12-3-4-frac-13-4-5)

Comment: That isn't fully partial fractioned. You have to decompose all of the terms to get the telescoping series.

Comment: Thanks @ParclyTaxel