Finding the limit of a series with partial fraction decomposition.
The limit of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {2} {(n+1) *(n+2) * (n+3)} $ is sought;
via partial fraction decomposition I simplified the series to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n+1} - \frac {2} {n+2 } + \frac {1} {n+3} $. Computing the first ten partial sums showed me that that this series might be a telescoping series, if we index the partial sums beginning with i= 1 I noticed that the first term of a partial sum ,with an index that is an odd number, gets cancelled by the second term of the partial sum with index i*2, so that in odd numbered indexes the first term is cancelled and in even numbered indexes both the first and second terms of the partial sum get cancelled. That's all I got so far and I wondered if I am onto something, but just can't connect the dots or if I am completly wrong.

I suggest writing out several of the first few terms, so that you can see how the telescoping series works in this case. It is generally not a good idea to cancel out $a_i$ with $a_{2i}$, because you then run into convergence issues that isn't easily fixed. You want to cancel out $a_i$ with $a_{i+1}$, or at beast $a_{i+k}$ for a fixed $k$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1663080/42969

(Too long to be a comment. Not a complete answer.
For context, OP originally responded to my comment wrtiing out terms all in a row, and stated they didn't know how to proceed. However, the comment was then deleted.)
Here is how I suggest writing out the first few terms.
$$\begin{array} { l l l l l } 
\sum a_i = \frac{1}{1} & - \frac{1}{2} & + \frac{ 1}{3} \\
  &+ \frac{1}{2}  & - \frac{2}{3} & + \frac{1}{4} \\
&  &+ \frac{1}{3}  & - \frac{2}{4} & + \frac{1}{5} \\
&&  &+ \frac{1}{4}  & - \frac{2}{5} & + \frac{1}{6} \\
& \vdots \\
\end{array} $$
What can you say from here?
What observations do you have about the columns?

Upvoted if only for the typesetting.

An easier way to do it is :
Break and Separate the terms-
$\frac{2}{n+2}$ into -$\frac{1}{n+2}$ and -$\frac{1}{n+2}$
$$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}$$ and  $$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{1}{n+3}- 
 \frac{1}{n+2}$$
Now, I hope you can solve and visualise the telescopic  easily.
